Getting this error "Web3.providers.HttpProvider is not a constructor"

const provider=new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/XB5meeKTzn4rqhq0KyhkwS11mpP7mki1");
                ^

TypeError: Web3.providers.HttpProvider is not a constructor
    at connect (/home/siddhu_from_sklm/Desktop/web3learning/WEB3.JS/connetToBlockcahin.js:4:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/siddhu_from_sklm/Desktop/web3learning/WEB3.JS/connetToBlockcahin.js:8:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49


I've answered by guessing what might be causing the error. If you still face the error, then please add some reproducible code in your question.

You might be importing web3 library like this:
const Web3 = require('web3');

But, you've to import it like this:
const { Web3 } = require('web3');

